Why does OpenMDAO's auto coloring select more forward mode colors than expected for a block-diagonal Jacobian structure?
I have an structural optimization problem in OpenMDAO in a form where the objective (mass) depends on all design variables, however the constraints are formed in such a manner that they depend only on select design variables giving the Jacobian a block diagonal structural apart from the objective

I would have expected this to collapse down to 3 colors (2 fwd, 1 rev) in a manner similar to that described in Using Graph Coloring To Compute Total Derivatives More Efficiently in OpenMDAO, however the auto coloring algorithm is selecting 6 forward colors (1 for each design variable).

Have I misinterpretted how bidirectional coloring should work? Or am I likely missing something in the implementation. Is there a way to force the color for a certain response (in this case the objective) to be in reverse mode?
Note: I know the problem size shown isn't particularly large, but the same this is observed for larger problems of the same format.

I can't see any reason why the optimal coloring here should be more than 3, as you say.
The coloring algorithm is heuristic and isn't guaranteed to find the optimal coloring, so it's difficult to say if this is a failure or if it's just the performance of the algorithm in that case.
I'll write a test case for this matrix structure and see if I can reproduce it.

Just to update, we think we've identified a bug that will correct this behavior, I'll post here when it makes it to a release.

Perfect, thank you! If there's a branch or PR with the fix, I'd be happy to test it out with a few problems of this general structure

I put up a branch here: https://github.com/naylor-b/OpenMDAO/tree/coloring_ok with a fix for the coloring bug.
